# Thread output to GUI Text Field

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

I am trying to have the output in a TextField in a GUI but all I am getting is the thread information. This is just a small set from the full code but the full version has the same problem. The full version has 5 different threads running at the same time. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

```
public class O21 implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        Scanner O1 = new Scanner(new File("O21.txt"));
        O1.useDelimiter(",");
        while (O1.hasNext()) {
            String a = O1.next();
            int aa = Integer.parseInt(a);
            Thread.sleep(500); // Time delay to sync output
            if (a.trim().isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    } catch (Exception f) {
        f.printStackTrace();
    }}}
```

This is the main.

```
public class Window {
    private JFrame frmTest;
    private JTextField txtTank1;
    private JTextField textField_4;
    static String o1;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Thread a = new Thread(new O21());
    a.start();

    o1= a.toString();

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Window window = new Window();
                window.frmTest.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Window() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frmTest = new JFrame();
    frmTest.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    frmTest.setResizable(false);
    frmTest.setBounds(100, 100, 350, 400);
    frmTest.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmTest.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    txtTank1 = new JTextField();
    txtTank1.setText("Tank1");
    txtTank1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    txtTank1.setEditable(false);
    txtTank1.setColumns(10);
    txtTank1.setBounds(10, 60, 150, 50);
    frmTest.getContentPane().add(txtTank1);

    textField_4 = new JTextField();
    textField_4.setEditable(true);
    textField_4.setText(o1);
    textField_4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    textField_4.setColumns(10);
    textField_4.setBounds(170, 60, 150, 50);
    frmTest.getContentPane().add(textField_4);
}}
```

Comment: Please see edits to answer, including code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're writing to o1 once, and only getting the default `toString()` from thread, so I'm not surprised that you're seeing nothing but junk. My suggestion:

- Create a `SwingWorker<Void, String>` inside of your GUI
- Run your long running code from within the SwingWorker's doInBackground
- Publish any Strings that the GUI needs by calling `publish(...)`, passing in the String.
- Display them in the GUI using the SwingWorker's `process(...)` method.
- Don't use a static variable as a kludge to communicate between threads. That is a very easily breakable non-solution.
- Avoid calling `setBounds()` in a Swing GUI. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one. Instead learn about and use layout managaers.
- Have a look at: [Tutorial: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

---

e.g. something like,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingThreadingEg extends JPanel implements MyAppendable {
   private JTextArea area = new JTextArea(30, 50);

   public SwingThreadingEg() {
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(area);
      scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
      add(scrollPane);
   }

   @Override
   public void append(String text) {
      area.append(text);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SwingThreadingEg mainPanel = new SwingThreadingEg();
      MyWorker myWorker = new MyWorker(mainPanel);
      // add a Prop Change listener here to listen for 
      // DONE state then call get() on myWorker
      myWorker.execute();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SwingThreadingEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {
   private MyAppendable myAppendable;

   public MyWorker(MyAppendable myAppendable) {
      this.myAppendable = myAppendable;
   }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
      try (Scanner O1 = new Scanner(new File("O21.txt"))) {

         O1.useDelimiter(",");
         while (O1.hasNext()) {
            String a = O1.next();
            int aa = Integer.parseInt(a);
            Thread.sleep(500); // Time delay to sync output
            if (a.trim().isEmpty()) {
               continue;
            }
            System.out.println(a);
            publish(a);
         }
      } catch (Exception f) {
         f.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
      for (String text : chunks) {
         myAppendable.append(text + "\n");
      }
   }
}

interface MyAppendable {
   public void append(String text);
}
```

Comment: Why OP's `window.frmTest.setVisible(true);` does not throw an `NPE`?

Comment: @PM77-1: no idea. I gave up looking in detail at his code as soon as I saw him calling `toString()` on a thread!

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed. I couldn't get the strings to output correctly. And *window.frmTest.setVisible(true);* was autogenerated by the window builder.